# In Orchard cms I want to include certain .js files, where should i put them and how should i include it in my project?

Tags: javascript, orchardcms

In Orchard cms I want to include certain .js files, where should i put them and how should     i include it in my project?
I am using "TheThemeMachine" as the theme of my project, so i created a folder js and clubed all the .js files require to me in this folder.
Now in my Layout.cshtml

i have included in this manner my other .js files
But it gives me error in console that

> mywebsite/Themes/TheThemeMachine/js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js
>   404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

to include script files first put you'r script in `Scripts` directory then simply try following

```
Script.Include("jquery-1.8.0.min.js");
```

by the way , this is not the correct way of including `Jquery library` in your theme.Jquery have been registered as a global resource by `Orhard.jQuery` module thus to include jquery try this :

```
Script.Require("jQuery");
```

this will ensure that jQuery included only once.but if you insist in putting script files in `js` directory then you can try this trick.

```
Script.Include("../js/yourscript.js");
```

don't forget to put a copy of `web.config` (one exist in Scripts directory) file in your `js` directory unless you'r script file will never been detected.

**edit :**

making change to ThemeMachine is not a good habit.try creating your own theme based onThemeMachine  by means of orchard command line .this is the way to go :

```
codegen theme <theme-name> [/CreateProject:true|false][/IncludeInSolution:true|false][/BasedOn:<theme-name>]
```

for example :

```
codegen theme MyTheme /CreateProject:true /IncludeInSolution:true /BasedOn :TheThemeMachine
```

orchard command line is an exe file resides in `/bin` directory(**note that you must copy this file to `Orchard.Web` directory before executing it**).
this will create Scripts and Styles directory automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, But I am unable to find Scripts directory, could you please give me the path where exactly i have to paste

Comment: you can create such a directory yourself.i have updated code.check it.

Comment: Thanks now my js files can read by adding web.config in the scripts folder

Comment: Can you add a script reference to just one page in the CMS instead of adding it to Layout.cshtml where it would be included on every page?

Comment: @spadelives i couldn't understand you completely.could you please make your question more clear?

Comment: @BehnamEsmaili, the question was regarding how to include a js file in the Layout.cshtml template. However, this solution would result in a situation where the referenced js file would be included in every page that is based up on that template, which is sub-optimal if the js file is only needed on a single page. My question was how to avoid adding unnecessary weight throughout the site by referencing the js file only on the page where it is needed. Subsequently, I learned that one can include the script directly in the body of a page. I imagine you could also override the template.

Comment: @spadelives as i understood your problem is referencing one js file while making sure it is referenced only once.if this is the case then you can do it by means of `Script.Require()` function.if you need any further information about how to register scripts by your module to use with this function let me know.